# Show the format XX:00 in JAVA

Tags: java, number-formatting

I want to show a number in a format XX:00 in Java. How can I do it?

Ex: int number = 12;
    show 12:00.

```
double i = 12;
show 12:00
```

Comment: `i + ":00"`? Or use `String.format`

Answer (score 1):

### Showing a double number

If 12.0 is a fractional number to be printed with colon as decimal separator:

```
    double i = 12;
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator(':');
    NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00.00", dfs);
    System.out.println(format.format(i));
```

Output:

> 12:00

If `i` was 12.75 instead of 12, the fraction would be printed too:

> 12:75

It rounds to the nearest number with two decimals, so 12.756 would be printed as `12:76`.

### Showing a duration in hours and minutes

If instead your `12:00` denotes an amount of time, a duration in hours and minutes, we want something different because there are 60 minutes in an hour, not 100. Here’s the **Java 9** and later version:

```
    long totalMinutes = (long) (i * TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1));
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMinutes(totalMinutes);
    System.out.format("%02d:%02d%n", dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart());
```

This prints

> 12:00

or in the 12.75 case:

> 12:45

12.75 equals 12 and three quarters, and the 45 printed also equals three quarters of an hour, so this is what we wanted. It rounds down, so even though 12.759 equals 12 hours 45 minutes 32.4 seconds, it’s still printed as `12:45`.

**Java 8 and earlier:**
The `toMinutesPart` method I have used was introduced in Java 9. In Java 8 (and earlier) you may still use the `Duration` class, but it’s less advantageous, so you may also do without it:

```
    int hours = (int) i;
    long minutesOnly = totalMinutes - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    System.out.format("%02d:%02d%n", hours, minutesOnly);
```

Now the result is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = 12;
String.format("%.0f:00", i); // returns 12.00
```